# What the difference between on/at a hill

Tags: meaning, difference

It seems to me that *on a hill* has a subtle difference in connotation with *at a hill*. In my opinion, ***on** a hill* implies on the surface, while ***at** a hill* means a specific location. I am not sure if is a right understanding, but I am confused when I need to distinguish these two usages.

Do the following sentences have a different meaning?

> There is a flame **on** the hill.

> There is a flame **at** the hill.

Comment: My first thought would be that "**on** a hill" means "on [the top of] the hill", while "**at** a hill" likely means "at [the foot of] the hill". However, I doubt any set of dictionary definitions would make that a hard-and-fast distinction.

Comment: Thanks. Then does on a island and at a island make any difference?

Comment: Generally speaking --and it applies here--, "at" means roughly "in the area of". So, "on the hill" means somewhere between the base and the top of the hill", while "at the hill" means on or near the base of the hill.

Comment: This rule also implies that "on an island" means on the land itself, while "at an island" includes the island and the area surrounding it, like, "I anchored my boat at the island to do some fishing."

Answer (score 1):

Note that there may be regional differences here. For example, [New Yorkers famously wait *on* line, while most of the rest of the US waits *in* line](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2012/11/semantics-voting-you-say-line-i-say-line/321708/).

As a US-English speaker from California, I would say that *on a hill* indicates a physical location on an elevated area. For example from the lyrics of a great early Rock song, *I found my thrill, on Blueberry Hill*. *On a hill* and *on the hill* are commonly used phrases.

I do not recall hearing *at a hill*. If I were to hear it, I would imagine it as the abbreviation of *at the foot of a hill*. That is, standing in a place at the bottom of the hill. Another possibility is that the hill was a target, as in the following sentence.

> I aimed my missle at the hill.

Comment: @Young - It's generally best to include research you've done in the question itself, not in comments under the answers you get.

Answer (score 1):

Hills are geographical features or steep roads, the names of which are often inherited by human creations such settlements and municipal areas. For example Gipsy Hill in south London, which is both a physical hill **on** which something might be considered to be and a locality **at** (or **in**) which something might be. Likewise Winter Hill, which is a hill 465 metres high, and also sometimes considered  to be the name of the locality. Some UK reports about the fires use one, and some the other.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes it clear. I came across before some usage of on beach and at beach, is it the same way in their use? And if I use in with a locality, does it have a more connotation of boundary to this place.@Michael Harvey

Comment: In Britain, to be on the beach is to be physically located on the sand at the sea edge, and I daresay the US as well. In the US, to be at the beach is to be in an area or municipality with a beach. In Britain this is called being 'at the seaside'.

Comment: From a US English perspective, agreed with Michael Harvey. "On a beach" or, more frequently, "on the beach" mean feet on sand (or in the water). "At the beach" can mean feed on sand, but more frequently refers to the general seaside community.